# Is there a way to capture the content of the changed cells in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

There is a table in a worksheet. I want to use VBA to capture any changes made to that table. Is this possible?

For example, `C4 = 14` at the beginning. If user changes to `C4 = 18`, I want to know which cell is changed (`C4` in this case) and what has it been changed to (`18` in this case).

For advanced feature, if user adds a row, changing `C4` to `C5` (add a row above row 4), and add `C4 = 11` (new `C4`). Could this be captured? How about deleting original row 4? Could the deleted content be captured?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into the `Worksheet Change` event, and capture the cell (target) and compare to the new value.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: @CMArg Thanks. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer's no, not really.  By the time the worksheet change event is triggered, the target's value is the new value and the old value is lost.

I did once read of someone maintaining a hidden workbook that kind of mirrored every action that was done to the target workbook and could hence be used to track the changes.  But obviously this is a lot of effort.

An alternative might be to try something using Application.Undo.  So, from the worksheet change event, record what the value is, apply Application.Undo, record that value, then replace with the first value.  It's really messy though.

Comment: I am not following what you said. I tested Worksheet Change and Target, I can capture the changed value and added value after adding a row/column. However, I am having trouble capturing deleted content. Are you talking about this part?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  Yes, you can find out the new value, but my comments still stand with regards to deleted content.  The change event fires after the changes have been committed, so the original values are not available.

Comment: So far I cannot find a way to capture deleted content. Maybe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Say our table is **A1** through **D4**.  Enter the following code into the worksheet code area:

```
Public OldValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1:D4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Previous Value: " & OldValue & vbCrLf & "New value: " & Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Range("A1:D4"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            OldValue = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will work for simple single cell click and type edits.  `SelectionChange` detects and records the old value.  `Change` displays both the old value and the new value.

This will not work for multi-cell copy/pastes.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I did similar things. Now I can capture changed value and added value after adding a row/column. But I am having trouble capturing deleted content. Is there some way to capture the deleted values?

Comment: @NewGuyComesIn.............This simple approach only works for **single cell** changes..............capturing multi-cell changes like deleting an entire column is possible, but WAY MORE complex!